# Template is not found by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

```
Rails 5.1

In my controllers/fw_exports_conttroller.rb, I have:

def import_spreadsheet
  @import_spreadsheet = FwExport.new
  render template: "fw_exports/_import_spreadsheet"
end
```

When I select the menu item for this controller action, I get the following error message:

```
Processing by FwExportsController#import_spreadsheet as HTML
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template fw_exports/_import_spreadsheet with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/utils/rails/follower_wonk/app/views"
  * "/home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/devise_invitable-1.7.2/app/views"
  * "/home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/views"
):
FATAL -- : [d37603eb-3da3-4ad2-b81b-29198e6bb773] app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb:67:in `import_spreadsheet'
```

I verified that

```
app/views/fw_exports/_import_spreadsheet.html.slim
```

does exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting to render a `template` or a `partial`? Partials begin with `_`. Templates do not. Also, when rendering partials, do not include the `_` in the render statement. I'm guessing you want to `render partial: 'fw_exports/import_spreadsheet'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the "_" `fw_exports/_import_spreadsheet.html.slim` looks like a partial, when rendering partials you can skip the `partial` option and just pass the route of the file after the `views` folder, in your case:

```
def import_spreadsheet
  @import_spreadsheet = FwExport.new
  render 'fw_exports/import_spreadsheet'
end
```

Note `render 'fw_exports/import_spreadsheet'` will work even if the file doesn't have the "_" prefix, unlike the `template` option, that doesn't accept partial files.

Comment: nice! we have pretty much the same implementation to this solution. +1

Comment: This worked. I was trying it with template: there. When I removed template: it worked and of course I removed the underscore

Answer (score 2):

From the [Layout documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738836/rails-render-of-partial-and-layout-in-controller) it looks like you should not put the underscore of your partial.

The doc states that:

> Rails knows that this view belongs to a different controller because
>   of the embedded slash character in the string. If you want to be
>   explicit, you can use the :template option (which was required on
>   Rails 2.2 and earlier)

Which means that you do not need to provide the path to the controller since you are dealing with the same one here:

As per @SebastiánPalma suggested edit

```
def import_spreadsheet
  @import_spreadsheet = FwExport.new
  render "fw_exports/import_spreadsheet"
end
```

Should simply solve your problem. Also `template` was required prior to Rails V2.2 
 but since you are using 5.1 you are not required to use it. You could simply do `render 'import_spreadsheet'`

Comment: It worked for me as `render 'import_spreadsheet'`, using the `template` option gives me "Missing template /import_spreadsheet", it seems again, we're close enough - Rails 5.1.4.

Comment: I guess one needs to provide the relative path of the template to be rendered when using `template` thanks for that!

Comment: Quick question. Since the OP is in the `import_spreadsheet` action of the `FwExportsController`, couldn't the OP just have a view named `import_spreadsheet` and skip the render line altogether?

Comment: Yeah I think it should. Is that different for partial rendering? if not than there wouldn't be a need to explicitly render the template at the end of the action as you mention.

Comment: I *think* it's different for views than for partials. But, TBH, I don't know for a fact. I'll have to give it a go sometime.

Comment: @Cyzanfar your answer did not work. I've already tried it, prior to asking my question. I based my code on the link you reference in your answer

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper could you tell me what exactly did not work. I'm interested in seeing if there are other solutions that might work in this particular case

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I misread your answer (unless it was modified)

Answer (score 1):

Or, possibly:

```
class FwExportsController < ApplicationController

  def import_spreadsheet
    @import_spreadsheet = FwExport.new 
  end

end
```

If you have `app/views/fw_exports/import_spreadsheet.html.slim` (a view, not a partial), then I think it will render by default/convention.

Comment: most definitely an elegant solution +1!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just updated to Rails 5.1 and are seeing this error, it can also be caused by using `render nothing` in a controller since this method was removed in Rails 5.1. This is not always immediately apparent because sometimes the controller line can be a few levels deep in your stack trace. But if you check the line numbers of all the controllers in your stack trace and you spot a `render nothing`, you've found the culprit. If this is indeed your issue, all you need to do is replace this old method.

For example, if your old code was:
`render nothing: true, status: 403`

You could fix the error by changing it to: `head :forbidden`

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming that you need to render the `Template` not the `Partial`.

To render the `Template` you need to rename the `_import_spreadsheet.html.slim` to `import_spreadsheet.html.slim`.

The below modification you required in your code

**Step1**

```
def import_spreadsheet
  @import_spreadsheet = FwExport.new
  render template: "fw_exports/import_spreadsheet"
end
```

here you need to remove the `_` from `_import_spreadsheet`

**Step 2**

Rename the file to `app/views/fw_exports/import_spreadsheet.html.slim` instead of `app/views/fw_exports/_import_spreadsheet.html.slim`

Comment: There is no need to rename the template. Also if other views are rendering that partial this change will break those views.